# What's the custom URL for facebook to share a post on the timeline with a message and a link?

Tags: facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I have tried these and it opens facebook but not the create new status message window.

fb://post/?text=Hello

fb://profile/me/post/?text=Hello

fb://story/?text=Hello

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

See "URL Redirection":

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?
  app_id=145634995501895
  &display=popup
  &href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2F
  &redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Ftools%2Fexplorer
```

Although, i don´t know if it is possible to do that without a link. You will get redirected to the API Explorer if you omit the href parameter, and you will get an error if you omit the redirect_uri parameter.

The feed dialog still works, although it´s deprecated so it may get disabled sooner or later:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
  app_id=145634995501895
  &display=popup
  &redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Ftools%2Fexplorer
```

It does work even without the href parameter. Here´s a link to the docs for the parameters: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.1

**What you can´t do is predefine a message though.**